# How to filter results from ManyToManyField Table in django "admin.py"?

Tags: django, django-admin

Sorry for bad English and less information

```
# Models.py #
class Course(models.Model):
    course_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    short = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    elective_group = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.course_code

class Lecturer(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User)
    assigned_course = models.ManyToManyField(Course)

#admin.py#
from django.contrib import admin
from mysite.question_bank.models import *


class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('course_code', 'title', 'short' )
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(CourseAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs    #(all the courses)
        else:
            return qs.filter( ????? ) # particular courses for a username
```

A lecturer can be assigned as many as course.I want to return a  queryset with courses assigned for a particular username.

Answer (score 0):

> `return qs.filter( ????? )` # particular courses for a username

You can do

```
return request.user.lecturer_set.get().course_set.all()
```

Comment: can u please give a brief explanation about your answer to this question.